# Automation on Windows?

Tags: windows, browser, automation, monitor

i need to open at the startup of the pc 3 browsers on 3 different monitor starting from one Windows XP pc.
Then i need to set the 3 browser to full screen (F11) automatically.
I need another thing, on the startup I'll check the connection to internet, if the connection is down I need to show a message ( maybe from a local html file ) then I need to retry to open the 3 browser if the connection goes up.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You're welcome, but what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml). It's a scripting language built for Windows automation and can probably do all these things. And on the off-chance that you're doing this to view a specific website on a few available browsers, also check out [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Try [Windows Powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). To start the script at startup you could put it in the Startup folder. You can check for the Internet connection in Powershell as well. Opening a browser can be done following instructions at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338327/open-ie-maximized-from-powershell-script](http://Open%20IE%20Maximized%20from%20Powershell%20Script).

Your code would look something like:

```
$ie=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate($url1)
$ie.navigate($url2,0x0800)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous tools to do automation on Windows. As others mentioned Powershell comes from Microsoft and AutoIt is a free 3rd party tool.

If you are looking for a commercial automation tool try [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest/features/technologies/windows.html) (disclaimer: I work for the company).